# minima and second order derivative

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

let $E$  be a banach space and $f:E\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  differentiable

we know that $x_0$ is local minimizer , if there existe a neighborhood $ V\subset E$ such that  :

$f(x_0)\leq f(x)$ for all $x\in V$

and  a way to prove $x_0$ is local minimizer is to prove that $f^{'}(x_0)= 0$ and $f^{"}(x_0)>0$

I have a little confusion 
: I believe that if I can show that  $f^{'}(x_0)= 0$ and $f^{"}(x_0)\geq0$ 
we can easily see by Taylor expansion that $f(x_0)\leq f(x)$

I do not see where he is the problem

Comment: Try writing down your argument in detail and find the error. If you do not succeed post this detailed argument here and ask where the mistake is exactly. A counterexample would be $f(x)=x^3$.

Comment: thank you @humanStampedist  your contre example is great ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you @humanStampedist  your contre example is great ,

to simplify the notations i will take $ x_0=0$ and $F=f$ so

$F(t)=F(0)+ t F^{'}(0) +\frac{t^2}{2}F^{"}(0) + o(t^2)$ and we have $F'(0)=0$ 
so $F(t)=F(0)+\frac{t^2}{2}F^{"}(0) + o(t^2)$
as $F^{"}(0)\geq 0 $ then $\frac{t^2}{2}F^{"}(0) + o(t^2)$

this imlpies $F(t)=F(0)+\frac{t^2}{2}F^{"}(0) + o(t^2)\geq F(0)$

in this cases 0 is a local minimum

Comment: If $F''(0)=0$ then you only have $F(t)=F(0)+o(t^2)$ but you do not have a sign for $o(t^2)$ it may be positive and it may be negativ, as seen by $F(t)=t^3$. Therefore you cannot conclude $F(t)\geq F(0)$

Comment: thank you infinitely @humanStampedist